# Insert multiple records into a table based on AVG values from another table in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database with 2 tables.  The first "spec" is a specification table, the second 'log' is table containing logged entries of previous measurements.  Each part being logged is identified by a part number and test measurement.  There may be many log entries for any given part number, but only 1 entry per part number in the 'spec' database giving the actual specification.  What I need to do is obtain an average of the test measurement for every different part in the 'log' table, and insert this into the 'spec' table as a new specification.  The log table will have already have been corrected to remove outliers.

I have been able to update existing records in the 'spec' table, but have been unable to insert records that do not already exist.

This works

```
update no_flow.spec s join
 (select part, round(avg(cc),0) as avgcc
 from no_flow.log l
 group by part) l
 on s.part = l.part and l.avgcc > 0
 set s.cc = l.avgcc;
```

This does not work

```
INSERT INTO no_flow.spec set (part, cc) s join
  SELECT part, avg(cc)
  FROM no_flow.log l
  WHERE id != 0
  values (l.part, l.avgcc);
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a unique index on part in spec you could use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

It would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO noflow.spec (part, cc)
 select
   part as logPart,
   round(avg(cc),0) as avgcc
 from
   no_flow.log
 group
   by logPart
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cc = VALUES(cc);
```

This inserts all the records from the inner SELECT into the spec table.  When a given inserted record encounters a duplicate key error (i.e. there is already a record for the current part number) the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause updates the existing record by setting its `cc` column equal to the `cc` column on the record it was trying to insert.

Comment: Thanks.  Almost ... the ON DUPLICATE throws a  “Unknown column ‘avgcc’ in ‘field list’ error.   If I use cc = 100 it works.  Existing records show cc=100 and new ones show the expected average.  I need to investigate that error ...

Comment: @JackRoffel I've updated my answer with a correction that worked when I tested it.  In the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause, VALUES(cc) says to use the value that would have been inserted for cc if there hadn't been a duplicate key issue.